# When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to define the map │ keys statically in your configuration and place apply-time results only

Tags: terraform

How to work around this error? I have tried multiple ways but still it gives me the same error.

```
variable "pets_count" {
  type = number
}

resource "random_pet" "my_pet" {
  count = var.pets_count
}

resource "null_resource" "ckeck" {
  for_each =  {for pet in try(random_pet.my_pet.*.id, []) : pet => {"name" = pet}}

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${each.value.name}"
  }
}
```

this gives me the following error.

```
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│
│   on code.tf line 15, in resource "null_resource" "ckeck":
│   15:   for_each = local.pet_ids
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.pet_ids will be known only after apply
│
│ The "for_each" map includes keys derived from resource attributes that
│ cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the
│ full set of keys that will identify the instances of this resource.
│
│ When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to define the map
│ keys statically in your configuration and place apply-time results only in
│ the map values.
│
│ Alternatively, you could use the -target planning option to first apply
│ only the resources that the for_each value depends on, and then apply a
│ second time to fully converge.
```

I have tried some more ways of looping over but it still ended up with the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the code in two stages as indicated in the last line of the warning:

> you could use the -target planning option to first apply only the resources that the for_each value depends on, and then apply a second time to fully converge.

Either by editing the code (commenting out the `null_resource`) or as they say with `-target`.

The following sequence of actions with your code:

```
terraform apply -target 'random_pet.my_pet'
terraform apply
```

worked.

### Explanation

AFAIK, there's no way to force Terraform to perform two runs in one execution of the `apply` command. And basically two runs are needed to define your constellation of resources. Terraform (as most of the tools of the same principle) works in different phases - first it needs to establish what are the resources to be managed (created/destroyed/updated/imported/etc.) and then to perform these operations. Your code requires to execute: establish, then create, then establish, then create.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried the way you have suggested, and it works for me perfectly fine when I try from the terraform command line. But I am using terraform console. Trying to see if I have any workaround for this when I run the configuration from terraform console.

Answer (score 2):

The `for_each` feature is designed under the assumption that each instance of the resource will have a unique string identifying it, and that those strings will be known to Terraform throughout the plan/apply process so that it can track those objects between the phases and between plan/apply rounds.

Your configuration is try to use random strings generated during the apply phase as the tracking keys, and so it doesn't work because those random strings haven't yet been decided during the initial plan phase.

The error message is trying to suggest that you decide your keys in a different way so that they are based directly on something written in the configuration, rather than something that will be decided by a provider during the apply phase. In this contrived example the only available static identifier would be indices in the range 0 to `var.pets_count` -- derived from the number instance keys of `random_pet.my_pet` -- like this:

```
variable "pets_count" {
  type = number
}

resource "random_pet" "my_pet" {
  count = var.pets_count
}

resource "null_resource" "check" {
  for_each =  {
    for idx, pet in random_pet.my_pet.*.id :
    idx => {"name" = pet}
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${each.value.name}"
  }
}
```

If `var.pets_count` were 2 then this would declare instances like this:

- `null_resource.check["0"]`
- `null_resource.check["1"]`

In most cases there's something better to use as an identifier than a numeric index. For example, when declaring AWS VPC subnets it's common to use AWS availability zone names as the keys, in the common case where there's one subnet per availability zone, or at least one subnet *of a particular type* per availability zone.

It's important to choose identifiers carefully because they constrain how a system can evolve in future without disrupting existing objects. Using list indices as in my above example means that the only possible operations are to increase or decrease the number. In the AWS availability zone case though, it becomes possible to add or remove individual availability zones from consideration without disturbing the existing subnets that belong to other availability zones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This had worked intermittently. But when I tried to run the destroy plan I got the same error again.